# Will Apple reject the app if UIStatusBarForegroundView is used as string

Tags: ios, uiapplication, iphone-privateapi, uistatusbar

In my app I have need to trigger show some custom view when status bar is tapped. I figured out the way to get the event by subclassing UIApplication.

If I use the code below will Apple block my app for private API usage?

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [[event allTouches] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITouch * touch,BOOL * stop){
        if (touch.tapCount==1 && touch.phase==UITouchPhaseEnded) {
            NSString * touchedViewClassName = NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]);
            if ([touchedViewClassName isEqualToString:@"UIStatusBarForegroundView"]) {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"StatusBarTapped" object:nil];
            }
        }
    }];
    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

Please advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is against the interface and human guidelines

Comment: When I have two tableview I want to control which one scrolls to top when it status bar is tapped. This scrolling to top is already a feature in iOS. Why do you think it is against guidelines ?

Comment: I did a bit more research but I can't seem to find an answer, maybe you should directly contact apple. Try the review board:

Comment: appreview@apple.com

That is the app review board email you can send it emails which they will answer

Comment: Hi user1260708, I have emailed them the same query. Let me see if I get a reply. I will post whatever they email me back. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @imthi just curious.. did they reply yet?

Comment: Thank you for contacting the App Review team. While we cannot provide pre-approval for proposed application submission or review code, we do recommend that you review the App Store Review Guidelines against the specific application you wish to develop.  The App Store Review Guidelines can be found at https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

We strongly recommend reviewing “iOS Developer Program License Agreement” “iOS Human Interface Guidelines,” and “In App Purchase Programming Guidelines” to ensure that your application is in compliance with all documentation.